# How can i Auto redirect each post of my site to AMP Version on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, amp-html, auto

I want to auto-redirect each post of my website on mobile. I am using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ example.x/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript 
if the device is not desktop .redirect to the Amp version

```
<script>
    var isMobile = window.orientation > -1;
    if(isMobile){
        window.location.replace("{{ url('aboutUsAMP') }}");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I have to use auto redirection, on every page. by this method, I will have to do manually on each page which is not applicable.